# Automate Google Cloud Print from Drive Folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-print

To preface, I have Google Cloud Print working through apps script. I have OAuth2 setup, and I was able to setup a Cloud Print API that prints a single file in my Google Drive to a printer on my Cloud Print.

With that said, I'm looking for a way to automate my script so that when a document gets placed in a specific folder on my Google Drive, it will print automatically. I've searched around and was unable to find anything similar. Here's my starting point (which was found here from a very helpful tutorial):

```js
function printGoogleDocument(docId, docTitle) {
  // For notes on ticket options see https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd?hl=en
  var ticket = {
    version: "1.0",
    print: {
      color: {
        type: "STANDARD_COLOR"
      },
      duplex: {
        type: "NO_DUPLEX"
      },
    }
  };

  var payload = {
    "printerid": myPrinterId,
    "content": docId,
    "title": docTitle,
    "contentType": "google.kix", // allows you to print google docs
    "ticket": JSON.stringify(ticket),
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit', {
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getCloudPrintService().getAccessToken()
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  });

  // If successful, should show a job here: https://www.google.com/cloudprint/#jobs

  response = JSON.parse(response);
  if (response.success) {
    Logger.log("%s", response.message);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Error Code: %s %s", response.errorCode, response.message);
  }
  return response;
}
```

So when I fill in my docID and PrinterID, it works fine for a single document. But like I said, I'm trying to automate this based on new files in a Drive folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to check these tutorial if it can help you to automate the Google Cloud Print from your Drive folder. These tutorial will help you to get some ideas on how to do it. [Automatically Print Files Placed in Drive with Google Cloud Print and Apps Script](https://ctrlq.org/code/20061-google-cloud-print-with-apps-script), [How to Automate Printing From Your Website Using the Google Cloud Printing Service](https://premiumitsolutions.com.au/developers/how-to-automate-the-google-cloud-print-service/) and [Cloud Print Connector for GAS](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/guests/cloudprint)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The first link is what I followed to get to where I'm at now. However, I wasn't able to figure out the actual automation aspect when a file is placed in the drive. The third link I looked at significantly, but was ultimately unsuccessful. I'll check out the second link. I didn't even think about IFTTT.